# custom validation of django admin forms not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In my application I have some models, with their respectives ModelAdmins and ModelForms...

```
class Group(models.Model):
    pass

class Department(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToMany(Group, through='MyModel')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        'department.Department',
        related_name="group_memberships",
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        'group.Group',
        related_name="department_memberships",
    )

class MyModelInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        # some working formset validation here
        pass

class MyModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyModel
    extra = 1
    formset = MyModelInlineFormset

class DepartmentAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MyModelInline,)
```

I have validation already working at formset level, but now I want to set some validation for each inline. For that, I have added the following:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(GroupDepartmentMembershipForm, self).clean()
        delete_checked = cleaned_data.get('DELETE')
        department = cleaned_data.get('department')
        group = cleaned_data.get('group')
        if delete_checked:
            if not group.departments.exclude(pk__exact=department.pk):
                raise forms.ValidationError('orphan group!')
        return cleaned_data

class MyModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyModel
    extra = 1
    formset = MyModelInlineFormset
    form = MyModelForm
```

It looks ok, the behaviour seems ok on the debugger, the ValidationError is created but it never reaches the browser, the performed validation doesn't have any effect.

I have found out that when I validate at FormSet level it works properly. But it's not the same at Form level. Any idea to fix the inline Form validation?

Comment: i am facing the same problem..were you able to find a fix ??

Comment: It seems a bug within django admin. I had to find a workaround for my special case to get rid of the inlines and validate them as usual.